# Grab icon_url with Item Name [Steam-Web-API]

Tags: php, steam-web-api

Is there a way to generate the icon_url from the skins name? So for example.

StatTrak™ AUG | Ricochet (Factory New)

From that to get the icon_url that would be

http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot6-iFAZt7PLddgJI-dG0mIW0m_7zO6_ummpD78A_jrGXrNykiQDmrUFvaj2nd4WcIVI4ZV2E-AC_xuznhJ60vcucynU3vz5iuyiL80cXxw/330x192

I only have the name, nothing else of the item. I was thinking about making a scraper that would search it on the market place then get the URL from there.